# Python Ctypes, C++ String to float conversion gives wrong/rounded result after calling Matplotlib in python

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, floating-point

I have a C++ function that is called from Python via ctypes. I observe some strange behavior when converting a string to float or double after calling a matplotlib funcion in my python code. The conversion suddenly seems to stop before the decimal point after calling a matplotlib function. Has anybody an idea, why this is happening, and how this can be prevented?

Here is my C++ funcion:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
void printDouble() {
    double result = stod("3.1415926");
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path

lib_path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute() / "str2double.so"

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)

# prints correct result
print("String to double conversion before matplotlib:")
lib.printDouble()

# some matplotlib function 
plt.plot(range(10))

print("String to double conversion after matplotlib:")
# after calling matplotlib function result is wrong
lib.printDouble()
```

If I execute my python script I get the following output:

```
String to double conversion before matplotlib:  
3.14159  
Icon theme "gnome" not found.  
String to double conversion after matplotlib:  
3
```

I am running Kubuntu 19.10 and use Python 3.7.5, Matplotlib 3.1.2 and g++ 9.2.1
Note: Using atof instead of stof/stod shows the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this behavior. Matplotlib seems to modify setlocale to the system language which is German in my case. Therefore the decimal separator changes to ",".